# Joomla virtuemart simple cart total in add fix price

Tags: joomla

I am using virtue-mart version 2.6.8 with joomla 2.5.22
I want to add additional cost on products and i need to add dorpdown box on product detail page like 700 and 1500 additional cost.

Price of product $10 and user will add 100 products and select from dropdown 700 then in cart its shows like:

10(price) * 100(quantity) = 1000 (cart total)

And 700 add on total amount of that product cost.

So final calculation should be 1000(cart total) + 700(add additional cost as per selecting dropdown extension) = 1700(we need this)

Note : Its for particular products of category.

please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a cart variant custom field (from custom fields menu) and add the fix price value there.

```
Virtuemart -> Custom Fields -> New -> Custom Field Type: Cart Variant / Cart Attribute: Yes
```

If you don't want to show this fixed price to the client you have to change with css the visibility of the field `display:none;`.